# PDFBOX Print via command line to specific computer/printer

Tags: windows, printing, pdfbox

I am trying to use pdfbox to print to a specific printer on a networked computer with the following command line:

```
java -jar D:/wamp/www/pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar PrintPDF -silentPrint -printerName "\\computer name\printer name" "D:\wamp\www\temp\file.pdf"
```

When I print to networked printer, it works fine:

```
java -jar D:/wamp/www/pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar PrintPDF -silentPrint -printerName "networked printer name" "D:\wamp\www\temp\file.pdf"
```

Any ideas?